# parse and process HTML/XML/plain text page

Tags: php, html, regex, xml, dom

I am creating a small php app that pulls data from a remote website its working great but i would like to make it more user friendly now.

I need to get a few specific items from the page and as far as I can tell the page looks like an xml file wen you look at sorce code but it has no style to it and appears as plain text so I don't really know what to do.

The page I am trying to get looks like this

```
    <channel>
      <name>data</name>
      <id>data</id>
      <img>data</img>
      <auther>data</auther>
      <mp3>data</mp3>
      <bio>data</bio>
   </channel>
    <channel>
      <name>data</name>
      <id>data</id>
      <img>data</img>
      <auther>data</auther>
      <mp3>data</mp3>
      <bio>data</bio>
   </channel>
    <channel>
      <name>data</name>
      <id>data</id>
      <img>data</img>
      <auther>data</auther>
      <mp3>data</mp3>
      <bio>data</bio>
   </channel>
    <channel>
      <name>data</name>
      <id>data</id>
      <img>data</img>
      <auther>data</auther>
      <mp3>data</mp3>
      <bio>data</bio>
   </channel>
```

I need to get all the data from each tag under the channel tag and keep it in the same order to echo it back out onto my own page in the same way.

How could i do this ? i tried using regex with the following patter

```
    $pattern = '<channel>
      <name>(.*)</name>
      <id>(.*)</id>
      <img>(.*)</img>
      <auther>(.*)</auther>
      <mp3>(.*)</mp3>
      <bio>(.*)</bio>
   </channel>';
```

but that doesn't work I really need the best and simplest way to do this.

Comment: maybe `SimpleXMLElement` would be better way to get data from it?

Comment: you mean something like

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($input);
        $callback = $xml->{"name"};

but how would i go about getting all the values under each channel and keeping them the same to echo out again as i think just getting them like that could mix stuff up from other channels no ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$SimpleXMLElement = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
foreach ($SimpleXMLElement->children() as $Channel) {
    foreach ($Channel->children() as $Child) {
        echo $Child->getName() . ' = ' . (string) $Child;
    }
}
```

this way you can use `SimpleXMLElement`, it's very easy

Comment: i need to beable to get every tag under the channel tag one by one and echo them or encode them 

i dont see how this can be done using this method seen as i dont know witch ones are witch

Answer (score 0):

I would "sanitize" the incoming data and make an xml document out of it. This can be done by simply wrapping it into a surrounding tag. (I name it `channels`). Having this, you can parse the data using `DOM`:

```
// Sanitize input data. Make an xml out of it
$xml  = '<channels>';
$xml .= file_get_contents($url);
$xml .= '</channels>';

// Create a document
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

// Iterate through channel elements
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('channel') as $channel) {
    echo $channel->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
    echo $channel->getElementsByTagName('id')->item(0)->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
    // And so on ...
}
```

Comment: this way looks easy and good if i ever need to edit it i am gonna try it now

Comment: this is not working it adds the </channels> to the bottom on a new line but wen its adding the first </channels> tag its on the same line as <channel> and shows up as red

Comment: what??? Sorry I don't get you.

Comment: it wasnt putting a space after sanatising to create xml file i fixed that with PHP_EOL it creates the file fine and if i echo it out it works greate i can see every thing 

but wen i try get the bits i need from inside every channel i get a blank page

Comment: I've tested it with the input data you've posted - it works

Comment: hmm well wen it comes to live test i can get as far as grabbing the data and creating the xml file but other than that it wont echo out the specific name or auther

Comment: do you have teamviewer maybe you could help me live ?

Comment: i have tried it with error reporting and i am getting this Fatal error</b>:  Class 'DOMDocument' not found on line <b>35

Comment: Which version of PHP you are using?